# How can I solve the issue with authorization?

Tags: javascript, axios

I have an issue with sign up.

When I try to sign up, server responses with 401 Unauthorized

This problem happens only when I start this project on localhost using docker. If I git clone project on my localhost - it works, but when I use docker - it doesn't

Request:
POST /auth/signup HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer null

Response:
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

There is code below:

```
//authApi.js
import {$api_id} from '../api'
export const AuthApi = {
      async signup(payload) {
          const response = await $api_id.post('/auth/signup', payload)
          return response
     },
     async signin(payload) {
          const response = await $api_id.post('/auth/signin', payload)
          return response
     }
}

//storage.js
const storage = {
    get: (key) => {return localStorage.getItem(key)}
}

export const getAccessToken = () => {
    return storage.get('accessToken')
}

//api.js
import axios, {AxiosResponse} from 'axios'
import {getAccessToken, getDeviceId} from 'utils'

export const API_URL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY

$api_id.baseURL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY

export const $api_id = axios.create({
    withCredentials: false,
    baseURL: API_ID_URL,
})

$api_id.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${getAccessToken()}` //getAccessToken(storage.get('accessToken'))
    if(config.data.avatar) {
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('deviceId', getDeviceId()) //getDeviceId(storage.get("deviceId")) - fingerprintjs
        Object.entries(config.data).forEach(([name, value]) => {
            formData.append(name, value)
        })
        config.data = formData
    } else {
        let data
        if(typeof config.data === 'string') {
            data = JSON.parse(config.data)
        } else {
            data = config.data
        }
        if(!data.deviceId) {
            data.deviceId = getDeviceId()
        }
        // console.log({data})
    }
    return config
})
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you confirm if the getAccessToken() function returns the token correctly, and also if the function is getting stored in localStorage

Comment: @Divyessh, this error happens only when I start this project on my local machine using docker.   I checked my local storage and there is no token

Comment: As long as we don't get to see how the `getAccessToken` function works, we can't really help you.

Comment: @EmilKarlsson, I edited question and added the function inside

Comment: You have withCredentials false. That needs to be true

Comment: @DanielA.White, it doesn't work